# TypeError: allocator undefined for Proc when working with a model object in a Rails 3.2 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I work with object of type Staffer, which inherits User which inherits ActiveRecord::Base  I get the error "TypeError: allocator undefined for Proc".

I'm not sure what caused it to start happening and unfortunately it won't be easy to track down the commit that did. Since the system was working properly, user.rb didn't change and staffer.rb only change one line to remove an unused constant.

I first noticed the error when running a rake task and the error is generated from a line that does this:

```
attributes.slice("id", "email", "state")
```

further investigation showed that this triggers the error too:

```
puts attributes
```

and this is the backtrace:

```
rake aborted!
allocator undefined for Proc
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:227:in `allocate'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:227:in `revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `block in revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `map'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:116:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:116:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:8:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `block in revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `map'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `block in revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `map'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `revive'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:191:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `each_slice'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb:25:in `to_ruby'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:107:in `load'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:24:in `unserialize'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:15:in `unserialized_value'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:82:in `__temp__'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:46:in `type_cast_attribute'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:126:in `read_attribute'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:183:in `block in attributes'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:183:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:183:in `map'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:183:in `attributes'
/Users/pupeno/Documents/watu/app/models/staffer.rb:151:in `index'
```

Trying to figure out what was going on, I opened a rails console and just got the first staffer, to encounter the same error:

```
1.9.2-p290 :019 > s = Staffer.first
  Staffer Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Staffer') LIMIT 1
TypeError: allocator undefined for Proc
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:227:in `allocate'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:227:in `revive'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `block in revive'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `map'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in `revive'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/psych_ext.rb:119:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping_with_class'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:116:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:116:in `each'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:116:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
... 24 levels...
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:107:in `load'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:25:in `load'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:24:in `unserialize'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:15:in `unserialized_value'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:82:in `__temp__'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:46:in `type_cast_attribute'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:126:in `read_attribute'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:200:in `attribute_for_inspect'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:640:in `block in inspect'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:638:in `collect'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:638:in `inspect'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p290 :020 >
```

Comment: Are you using STI for your User->Staffer relationship?

Comment: @Vapire yes, I am. Not sure if that's relevant though, maybe it is;  but I want to avoid the usual 'Oh, you are using STI, so you deserve any error and there's nothing that can be done about it' attitude.

Comment: I won't give you that attitude :) I've looked over the internet regarding this type of error and it seems that it has something to do with serialization... Do you have any yaml-serialized data in one of your staffer/user fields?

Comment: @Vapire yes, I have a serialized attribute, it's a hash.

Comment: Ok... So I think it has to do with the serialized data not with your code. Check to see if in your serialized data there's a serialized Proc object or so... That should be the reason why it can't load, cause somehow Procs can't be serialized!? See [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?325798-Rails-Unserializing-an-attribute) forum post

Comment: @Vapire it seems you are right... some procs or proc-like objects generated by FactoryGirl are ending up serialized.

Comment: @Vapire the problem was that used to have a variable name being used in an after_create in FactoryGirl, I removed the variable but factory girl provides a method name, staffer.profile[name] just picked that method as the key to the hash. If you want, put it as an answer and I'll accept it so you get the proper credit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have any yaml-serialized data in one of your staffer/user fields?

If so I think it has to do with the serialized data not with your code. Check to see if in your serialized data there's a serialized Proc object or so... That should be the reason why it can't load, cause somehow Procs can't be serialized!?

See [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?325798-Rails-Unserializing-an-attribute) forum post.